# router.navigate not working after upgrading from angular 13 to 14

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade, nx-monorepo

I am in the middle of upgrading angular 13 to 15 via 14.

Facing the below routing issue after upgrading from angular 13.4.0 to 14.0.7.  Respective NX versions 14.1 to 14.2

I have a couple sub applications hosted in a dashboard.  (supplier, customer).

Dashboard to any supplication and from sub application back to dashboard are working. (host  <-> host/supplier )

But internal routing with the sub application are not working. (host/supplier/supplier-add). Same code works in 13.4.0. But having this issue when upgrading to 14.0.x.

**app-routing.module.ts (dashboard)**

```
const DASHBOARD_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
  path: 'supplier',
  loadChildren: () =>
      loadRemoteModule({
        type: 'module',
        remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js',
        exposedModule: './Module',
      })
        .then((m) => m.SupplierRemoteEntryModule)
        .catch((e) => console.log(e)),
  },
  {
    path: 'customer',
    loadChildren: () =>
      loadRemoteModule({
        type: 'module',
        remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4202/remoteEntry.js',
        exposedModule: './Module',
      })
        .then((m) => m.CustomerRemoteEntryModule)
        .catch((e) => console.log(e)),
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardLandingComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent,
  },
];
```

**supplier-search.component.html**

```
<h5 id="add-supplier"
          role="button" 
          (click)="addSupplier()">
        Add New Supplier
  </h5>
```

**supplier-search.component.ts**

```
  public addSupplier(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['supplier-add'], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
```

**app-routing.module.ts (supplier component)**

```
const SUPPLIER_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SupplierAppComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: SupplierSearchComponent
      },

      {
        path: 'supplier-add',
        component: SupplierAddComponent
      {
        path: 'supplier-edit/:supplierId',
        component: SupplierEditComponent

      }
    ]
  },
];
```

Tried

```
 this.router.navigate(['supplier-add']);
```

In this case, url in the address bar stays `` (`host/supplier`) ``) but page is not loading. No errors or warnings.

Tried

```
this.router.navigate(['/supplier/supplier-add'])
```

In this case, lost the 'supplier' segment from the url (`host`)  Got the below error:

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'supplier/supplier-add'`

This issue still continues when I further upgrade to 15.x as well.

Comment: *"internal routing with the sub application are not working"* - what behavior do you see?  does it navigate to incorrect url? Does it not navigate at all? Are there any errors in the console?